# Array changes dimensions inside for loops or functions

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I have 2 big arrays with shapes (65000, 5) and (65000, 2), but for some reason when I access them inside for loops or functions the dimensions change randomly.
Here is an example of where it happens, I test the array before the for loop and inside the for loops and the results are different.

```
for test_i in range(len(norm_data)):
    if len(norm_data[test_i]) != norm_row_length:
        print("len(norm_data[", test_i, "]) = ", len(norm_data[test_i]), " should be ", norm_row_length)
    if len(vector_data[test_i]) != vector_row_length:
        print("len(vector_data[", test_i, "]) = ", len(vector_data[test_i]), " should be ", vector_row_length)


for index in range(start, training_len):
    x_rows = []
    for prev_i in range(n_prev):

        for test_i in range(len(norm_data)):
            if len(norm_data[test_i]) != norm_row_length:
                print("in loop len(norm_data[", test_i,"]) = ", len(norm_data[test_i]), " should be ", norm_row_length)
            if len(vector_data[test_i]) != vector_row_length:
                print("in loop len(vector_data[", test_i,"]) = ", len(vector_data[test_i]), " should be ", vector_row_length)
```

And this is part of the output:

```
in loop len(norm_data[ 0 ]) =  7  should be  5
in loop len(norm_data[ 1 ]) =  9  should be  5
in loop len(norm_data[ 2 ]) =  11  should be  5
in loop len(norm_data[ 3 ]) =  13  should be  5
in loop len(norm_data[ 4 ]) =  15  should be  5
in loop len(norm_data[ 5 ]) =  15  should be  5
in loop len(norm_data[ 6 ]) =  15  should be  5
```

EDIT:
I found the problem. The rest of the code inside the loop was modifying the array.

```
row_index = index - (n_prev-prev_i)
x_row = norm_data[row_index]
x_row += vector_data[row_index]
x_rows.append(x_row)
```

This was taking rows from norm_data by reference instead of copying them and modifying them afterward. The solution was copying the row.

```
row_index = index - (n_prev-prev_i)
x_row = list(norm_data[row_index])
# or x_row = norm_data[row_index][:]
x_row += vector_data[row_index]
x_rows.append(x_row)
```

Comment: On what basis have you decided that these lengths should be 5?

Comment: I guess you will achieve a better result using `enumerate()` instead of a combination of `range()` and `len()`. See <https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html>.

Comment: I save the dimensions in norm_row_length after I add the data into the array. I this case is 5.

Comment: When I run this, norm_data is not defined. Also, you talked about a function, but there is no function. Were you expecting an answer? Either python doesn't work, or you changed the data, or you aren't measuring what you think you are. I highly doubt it's the first option.

Comment: @ Kenny Ostrom this is just the part of the code where I run the test, I have run the test also inside functions and got the same result, with dimensions changing, and I am 100% sure that I have not changed the arrays.

Comment: The fact of the matter is you can be 100% sure of something and be wrong, and that happens all the time, to everybody. Your question doesn't do anything to illustrate the problem. What you say you believe is happening is irrelevant (and wrong). Post a [mcve]

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom you were right I was modifying the array inside the loop, I have edited the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following up my comment, here is a sample of the first loop using `enumerate()`:

```
for i, row in enumerate(norm_data):
    if len(row) != norm_row_length:
        print("len(norm_data[{}]) = {} should be {}".format(i, len(row), norm_row_length))
    if len(vector_data[i]) != vector_row_length:
        print("len(vector_data[{}]) = {} should be {}".format(i, len(vector_data[i]), vector_row_length))
```

It also replaces those string composition with `format()`. It is clearer and more Pythonic.

Comment: I tested it but I get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: And this is only my testing data, in the future my arrays will be much bigger.

Comment: It was my fault. I forget to use `enumerate()` in the original example. Could you test it again?

Comment: Yeah :) I just did that but then the code runs and produces the same problem, changing the dimensions of the array

Comment: Could you put a complete example with what we can reproduce the problem? You will get better answers that way. :-)

Comment: Ok I´ll do that

Comment: I have created this small test but there is no problem, in this case. The only thing I can think of is a memory issue or something like that as in my real code I have move big arrays etc...

Comment: arr = []

for i in range(650000):
    arr.append([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])

for z in range(4):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if len(arr[i]) != 5:
            print("len(arr[", i,"]) = ", len(arr[i]), " should be ", 5 )

print("first done")


for s in range(4):
    for d in range(4):
        for z in range(4):
            for i in range(len(arr)):
                if len(arr[i]) != 5:
                    print("len(arr[", i,"]) = ", len(arr[i]), " should be ", 5 )

print("second done")

Comment: I had to guess on indentation and remove some no-ops, but it worked as expected for me, and never printed a length mismatch.

Comment: I was modifying the array inside the loop, I edited the question with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The rest of the code inside the loop was modifying the array.

```
row_index = index - (n_prev-prev_i)
x_row = norm_data[row_index]
x_row += vector_data[row_index]
x_rows.append(x_row)
```

This was taking rows from norm_data by reference instead of copying them and modifying them afterward. The solution was copying the row.

```
row_index = index - (n_prev-prev_i)
x_row = list(norm_data[row_index])
# or x_row = norm_data[row_index][:]
x_row += vector_data[row_index]
x_rows.append(x_row)
```